# SQL -Rounding and Padding zeros

Tags: sql

I want  the amount currently in decimals to be rounded off to nearest higher $ value and pad Zeros on the left. For example: 1244.45 should be '00001244' and 1244.95 to '00001245'

Tried

```
Right('0000' + [columnname], 8), Round(columnname, .01) as value
from Table.name
```

. It is Rounding off then trimming it.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: What is `Right('0000' + [columnname], 8)` attempting to do? For your value, `1244.45` that expression returns `4.450000`, which looks *very* wrong. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9C_mq54t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wanting four zeros padded, then you could `concat` your data.

```
with my_data as (
  select 1244.45 as amount union all
  select 1244.95 
)
select 
  amount, 
  concat('0000', cast(round(amount, 0) as int)) as new_col
from my_data
```

| amount | new_col |
| --- | --- |
| 1244.45 | 00001244 |
| 1244.95 | 00001245 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QSG74uwh)

Comment: Good to hear. Should this suffice, then please consider marking the Accept flag.

Comment: I'd rather _guess_ OP wants a total 8 digits, with leading zeros. Like 01234567 and 0000001.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare @n decimal(18,2) = 1244.95
declare @s varchar(30)

set @s = replace(str(convert(int,round(@n,0)),8),' ','0')

select @s
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. But this one is rounding off and not adding the padding.

Comment: uhm...the result was the one you asked in the post...00001245